# Python how to get angle from 3 points using panda dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the angle from 3 points using 6 values (x and y for each of the 3 points). These values are listed in a panda dataframe. However I get many values as output and they are not angles. Also let me know if you have any better idea on how to set the problem (the code I wrote is quite ugly, I know...). I tried different ways but this is the only one that I can use with panda dataframe, and I am quite new to python... Any insight would be helpful
Function to compute angles using 3 points

```
    def FindAngle3Points (a,b,c):
#a = np.array([6,0])
#b = np.array([0,0]) this is the vertex of the angle
#c = np.array([0,6])

    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b

    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)

    print(np.degrees(angle))
```

Function to compute angles from the 6 columns

```
def MakePointFromCoord(X1column, Y1column, X2column, Y2column, X3column, Y3column):
    alpha_column = []
    for x1 in X1column:
        for y1 in Y1column:
            for x2 in X2column:
                for y2 in Y2column:
                    for x3 in X3column:
                        for y3 in Y3column:
                            a = np.array([x1,y1])
                            b = np.array([x2,y2])
                            c = np.array([x3,y3])
                            alpha = FindAngle3Points(a,b,c)
                            alpha_column.append(alpha)
    return(alpha_column)
```

And this is the code I used:

```
# Create Pandas DataFrame 
import pandas as pd 

# Initialise data to lists. 
data = [{'x1': 1, 'y1': 2, 'x2':3, 'y2': 1, 'x3': 2, 'y3':3}, {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2':3, 'y2': 8, 'x3': 2, 'y3':3}, {'x1': 1, 'y1': 7, 'x2':5, 'y2': 8, 'x3': 4, 'y3':3}] 

# Creates DataFrame. 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the data 
df 

#Compute angles from 6 coordinates
MakePointFromCoord(df.x1, df.y1, df.x2, df.y2, df.x3, df.y3)
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output. data format too.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
from math import acos, degrees
import pandas as pd 

# Initialise data to lists. 
data = [{'x1': 1, 'y1': 2, 'x2':3, 'y2': 1, 'x3': 2, 'y3':3}, {'x1': 5, 'y1': 7, 'x2':3, 'y2': 8, 'x3': 2, 'y3':3}, {'x1': 1, 'y1': 7, 'x2':5, 'y2': 8, 'x3': 4, 'y3':3}] 

# Creates DataFrame. 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
angles=[]
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    x1,y1=df.x1[i],df.y1[i]
    x2,y2=df.x2[i],df.y2[i]
    x3,y3=df.x3[i],df.y3[i]
    a=((x3-x1)**2+(y3-y1)**2)**0.5
    b=((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)**0.5
    c=((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2)**0.5

    angle=degrees(acos((b*b+c*c-a*a)/(2.0*b*c)))
    angles.append(round(angle,2))

df['Angles']=angles
df.head()

    x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  Angles
0   1   3   2   2   1   3   36.87
1   5   3   2   7   8   3   74.74
2   1   5   4   7   8   3   64.65
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One issue with the code you provided is that it calculates angle up to 180 degrees, not 360. Is there a way to get 360 degrees?

Comment: meaning an angle in range [0-360], i.e. clockwise angle?

Comment: @Lukas_Skog, when an answer solves the problem or helps to solve it, please vote up or ACCEPT the answer. This is the right way to say "thank you". You will earn points as well as who answers! In this way, you push people to answer your question in some ways.

Comment: and, when there are more questions on the answer, also consider asking another question. It seems you are making the community solve your homeworks.